# Get ASPNET Control Value Using jQuery and Update Panel

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have an asp.net  button and an asp.net label in an update panel and when I click the button it updates the text of the label in the code behind. However when I try to get the updated value it just returns an empty value.

How do I get the updated value after the asynchronous postback has completed. I have included my code below.

Many thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.Application.add_init(function() {

        // Add ajax request handlers
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequest);

        // Raised after asynchronous postback has completed
        function EndRequest(sender, args) {
            var path = $('#<%=lblPath.ClientID %>').val();
            alert(path);
        }
    });
</script>

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
                    OnClick="Submit_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Label ID="lblPath" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: After reviewing the code again, it seems my first answer was incorrect, I updated to correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using the `.val()` method incorrectly.  [The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements.](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Instead of `.val()` use `.html()`

```
var path = $('#<%=lblPath.ClientID %>').html();
```

or `.text()`

```
var path = $('#<%=lblPath.ClientID %>').text();
```